# Is the three-body problem be resolved when we calculate the tree of Feynman diagrams for the three bodies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, three-body-problem

When I think about the n-body problem, it seems an issue of sequentiality. Most of our equations are based on the interaction between two bodies, where in a 3 body simulation, we execute the equations sequentially, affecting one body, then another, then another. But in reality for every instant those three bodies interact via the fundamental forces, the interactions are all taking eachother into account in those very instants - quantum mechanics included. It seems not a problem so much as a plain oversimplification.

In other words, there's (mostly) no such thing as a two body system whatwith just about everything being entangled in some way shape or form. So my question is, if we make Feynman Diagrams of every possible interaction between two bodies for a single instant, repeating for the next pair of bodies out of the three based on all the possible diagrams from the previous - a branching tree of possible outcomes - is one of the answers correct (usually the most likely set of interactions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but your intuition is incorrect (but see the end). Most physical models involve differential equations with multiple bodies that *simultaneously* affect each other: there are no sequential effects.

Numeric solutions of these equations also occurs in a parallel way: calculating the force of pairs of bodies in sequence, or on one body and then another, is usually too inexact and produces simulation artefacts. In a typical numeric solution all forces at an instant are calculated and then positions and momenta updated ([often in clever ways to make precision better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)).

Feynman diagrams are something very different from how classical mechanics works. In quantum mechanics they are *summed together* to get a probability amplitude rather than representing a search for which outcome happens.

The reason the 3-body problem is hard (it isn't so much unresolved as known to be unsolvable in general) is that the space of possible solutions is very complex: there are chaotic regions that can produce vastly different outcomes for inputs that are arbitrarily close to each other. There are no nice, analytic solutions that covers all of the dynamics. In many cases there are few if any conserved quantities beyond energy, momentum and angular momentum that allows us to determine what happens without performing a simulation or observe the actual system.

That said, you are still on to something: [one can look at individual 3-body encounters and analyse their statistics fairly well](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-019-1833-8). That allows doing something like Feynman diagrams, or at least speak of decay/scattering probabilities.

Comment: 'that simultaneously affect" There OP possibly means that equations are sequentially solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the initial state of your system that you use to compute the perturbation series is close enough to the final result then the perturbation series may converge. So the question is how close do you have to be. My intuition tells me 'quite close'. In conclusion you will have to solve your problem by a nonperturbative method. Then why do we need perturbation theory? It allows us to treat otherwise troublesome but relatively small contributions to the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian. In such case you can do the nonperturbative treatment on a simplified system and top it up with perturbation theory.